# VB6: How To Show SQLite in DataGrid

Tags: sql, vb6

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim sqlstr As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=" & App.Path & "/database.db;"
conn.Open

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM tblGiat", conn, adOpenKeyset

MsgBox "Total Number of records = " & rs.RecordCount

End Sub
```

I have successfully connected the database to VB6. Now I need help, how to display that database into DataGrid.

Comment: I think you will need to ask a much more specific question...

Comment: I have SQLite database.db, I want to display all fields into DataGrid. But I've found out how.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim sqlstr As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=" & App.Path & "/database.db;"
conn.Open

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM tblGiat", conn, adOpenKeyset

MsgBox "Total Number of records = " & rs.RecordCount

Set DataGrid1.DataSource = rs

End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).